# MySql is not updating

Tags: php

please help..i give up..

trying to update MySql table..
the file is settings.php (self-submitting)
form code is:

```
<form method="POST" action="settings.php">
  First Name <input type="text" name="fname" id="set_fname"  />
  Last name <input type="text" name="lname" id="set_lname"  />
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="set_email"  />
  mobile <input type="text" name="mobile" id="set_mobile" />
  Bio: <textarea name="bio" id="set_bio"  cols="" rows="5" maxlength="1000" ></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="personal_submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

php part

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];   

$fname_update =$_POST['fname'];
$lnam_update = $_POST['lname'];
$email_update = $_POST['email'];
$mobile_update =$_POST['mobile'];
$bio_update =$_POST['bio'];

$db_host="localhost";
$db_uname="admin";
$db_pass="mypass";
$db_db="main_db";
$db_table="mebers_general";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_uname","$db_pass") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db_db") or die("no database by that name");

if($_POST['fname']){

  $sql_personal_update=mysql_query("UPDATE members_general SET first_name='$fname_update' WHERE id='$id' ") or die (mysql_error()) ;
    if($sql_personal_update){
      echo "should be ok but no record is updated....Heeelppp";
      }else{
      echo "Smth is Wrong";
      }  
}
```

I get no errors..

as a result i get the echo string "should be ok but no record is updated....Heeelppp";
so it detects no problem in updating
I've tried the same query in phpMyadmin - works just fine. 
I checked the variables - they are not empty..
everything seems to be as it should.
Please help..stacked for 2 days already here//

Comment: Cargo-cult programming warning: `"$db_pass"`

Comment: You are not executing any query there. And, as your variable has content, it throws true.

Comment: alfabravo -i don't believe it...will check in 5 seconds...very stupid of me

Comment: I'm a bit sad that we got 3 answers so far and _all_ of them are using the deprecated mysql_query... :-/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson one step at a time ;-) He's using the deprecated _connect and _select_db functions in his original code as well, so for the sake of consistency and ease of editing.. But you're right, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user1726572 I see you added mysql_query to your question without any comment. Are you still having trouble with that added, or did it solve your problem?

Comment: 3 possibilities: `session_start()` is not called before you try to access the session. `$_POST['fname']` is not present (e.g. form is not POSTed) or `$_SESSION['id']` is not set or doesn't match a record in your table. You should print out the query to see what values are being populated in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
  $sql_personal_update=mysql_query("UPDATE members_general SET firs_name='".$fname_update."' WHERE id='".$id."' ") or die (mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: of course i forgot the mysql_query..but still nothing...i updated the original question as you advised..but nothing..

Comment: Try to concatenate the variables as I did, maybe this is the problem.
BTW, you have a security hole there (sql injection), you have to protect the $fname_update =$_POST['fname'];
like this:
$fname_update =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);

Comment: @user1726572 Javascript runs on the client, leaving escaping of database queries to it sounds like a bad idea. Anyone that can hand craft a request (there are plugins for that for most browsers) can inject anything.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, That's true. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, i will change the code after i get this thing working..)))
right now no one can inject even the correct string

Answer (score 4):

You are not actually RUNNING your query:

```
$sql_personal_update=("UPDATE members_general SET firs_name='$fname_update' WHERE id='$id' ") or die (mysql_error()) ;
                     ^^^^^--- where's mysql_query()?
```

It should be

```
$sql_personal_update = mysql_query(blah blah blah) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's because you're not actually calling the `mysql_query` function!

For starters, try

```
$sql_personal_update=mysql_query("UPDATE members_general SET firs_name='$fname_update' WHERE id='$id' ") or die (mysql_error()) ;
```

Also, is `firs_name` a typo, or did you really call your database column that?

EDIT: As JoachimIsaksson suggested, mysql_connect etc are deprecated. Use mysqli instead, like below:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_uname,$db_pass, $db_db) or die (mysql_error());
if($_POST['fname']){
    $sql_personal_update=$mysqli->query("UPDATE members_general SET first_name='$fname_update' WHERE id='$id' ") or die (mysql_error()) ;
    if($sql_personal_update) {
        echo "should be ok but no record is updated....Heeelppp";
    } else {
        echo "Smth is Wrong";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everything, guys, i just recoded all page from blank and it worked..have no idea what was the reason..maybe the 20th hour in a row of coding..thanx..